# CSS rotate causing pixels to render differently?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg icon that I rotate using the following CSS:

```
 .icon {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 0.4em;
   width: 0.4em;
   left: 0.2em;
   position: relative;
   top: 0.15em;
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

The same icon is repeated but at times its pixels get sort of 'warped'.

[image: Above is correct, below is warped.]

Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Did you notice browser differences?

Comment: @dakab the same thing is happening in ff, chrome and ie11.

Comment: Please make a testable sample (jsfiddle or snippet) that reproduces the problem so we can test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following CSS to your icon:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: See also [`font-smooth` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) for `-webkit/-moz` differences.